# Google API: getting Credentials from refresh token with oauth2client.client

Tags: python, google-api, google-plus

I am using googles official oauth2client.client to access the google
plus api.  I have a refresh token (that does not expire) stored in a database, and need
to recreate the temporary "Credentials" (access token) from that.

But I could not find a way to do this with to official library supplied by google.

So I hacked around it: used urllib to access the API that gives me a new
access_token from the refresh_token. Using the access_token I can then use the library.

I must be missing somthing!

```
from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import AccessTokenCredentials
from urllib import urlencode
from urllib2 import Request , urlopen, HTTPError
import json

# ==========================================

def access_token_from_refresh_token(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token):
  request = Request('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    data=urlencode({
      'grant_type':    'refresh_token',
      'client_id':     client_id,
      'client_secret': client_secret,
      'refresh_token': refresh_token
    }),
    headers={
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  )
  response = json.load(urlopen(request))
  return response['access_token']

# ==========================================

access_token = access_token_from_refresh_token(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REFRESH_TOKEN)

# now I can use the library properly
credentials = AccessTokenCredentials(access_token, "MyAgent/1.0", None)
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('plus', 'v1', http=http)
google_request = service.people().get(userId='me')
result = google_request.execute(http=http)
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to refresh the token while using AccessTokenCredentials ? I am trying to find out how to do that but there is no visible documentation around ...

Comment: Just to make a dent in the history, in case somebody else is hitting his/her head to the wall: Google's documentation is complicated (or incomplete) here. `AccessTokenCredentials` doesn't provide a way to refresh the token. So you need to use other types of credentials, as explained in the answers below two possible options came feasible to me: `OAuth2Credentials` and `GoogleCredentials` (`GoogleCredentials` extends `OAuth2Credentials`).

Answer (score 25):

I use: [oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.client.html#oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials)

```
    cred = oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials(access_token,client_id,client_secret,
                                          refresh_token,expires_at,"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",some_user_agent)
    http = cred.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    cred.refresh(http)
    self.gmail_service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=cred)
```

Comment: I want to use the **refresh_token** (saved in a database) to retrieve a new **access_token** later. If I use `oauth2client.client.GoogleCredentials`, as you've suggested here, should I save the **access_code** also along-with the **refresh_code** in my database for future use?

Comment: you can set `access_token` to `None` (as you're renewing the token anyway), and `expires_at` can be `None` as well

Answer (score 11):

You can construct an [`OAuth2Credentials`](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.client.html#oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials) instance directly like this:

```
import httplib2
from oauth2client import GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI, GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI, client

CLIENT_ID = '<client_id>'
CLIENT_SECRET = '<client_secret>'
REFRESH_TOKEN = '<refresh_token>'

credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials(
    access_token=None,  # set access_token to None since we use a refresh token
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
    refresh_token=REFRESH_TOKEN,
    token_expiry=None,
    token_uri=GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI,
    user_agent=None,
    revoke_uri=GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI)

credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())  # refresh the access token (optional)
print(credentials.to_json())
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())  # apply the credentials
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved this quite easily (you certainly miss [this documentation](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.client.html)). This is a snippet of my code that tries to use Picasa API to get all of album from active user:

```
    http = httplib2.Http(ca_certs=os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'])
    try:
        http = self.oauth.credentials.authorize(http)
        response, album_list = http.request(Picasa.PHOTOS_URL, 'GET')
        if response['status'] == '403':
            self.oauth.credentials.refresh(http)
            response, album_list = http.request(Picasa.PHOTOS_URL, 'GET')
        album_list = json.load(StringIO(album_list))
    except Exception as ex:
        Logger.debug('Picasa: error %s' % ex)
        return {}
```

Use the `refresh` method coming from [oauth2client.client.OAuth2Credentials](http://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/oauth2client.client.html). I think it's even okay to use `if response['status'] != '200'`. Got to check that!

Comment: The link is broken, can you refresh it?

Answer (score 5):

In case anyone is looking for the answer for how use a refresh token with `google_auth_oauthlib`, the following works for me:

```
flow.oauth2session.refresh_token(flow.client_config['token_uri'],
                                 refresh_token=refresh_token,
                                 client_id=<MY_CLIENT_ID>,
                                 client_secret=flow.client_config['client_secret'])
creds = google_auth_oauthlib.helpers.credentials_from_session(
    flow.oauth2session, flow.client_config)
```

I cannot find anywhere where this is documented though.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `requests` library as well:

```
import google.auth.transport.requests
import requests

request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()

credentials.refresh(request)
```

Here is my sample code on an active project:

```
acct_creds = {
  'token': self.attachment.account.google_drive_access_token,
  'refresh_token': self.attachment.account.google_drive_refresh_token,
  'client_id': settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  'client_secret': settings.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  'token_uri': 'https://37947.ngrok.io/authenticate/google/callback/',
  'scopes': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install',
}
credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(**acct_creds)
if credentials.valid:
    print("Credentials valid")
else:
    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    credentials.refresh(request)
```

[google.auth.transport.requests module](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.transport.requests.html)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend this method.

```
from oauth2client import client, GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI

CLIENT_ID = "client_id"
CLIENT_SECRET = "client_secret"
REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token"


credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials(
    access_token = None, 
    client_id = CLIENT_ID, 
    client_secret = CLIENT_SECRET, 
    refresh_token = REFRESH_TOKEN, 
    token_expiry = None, 
    token_uri = GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI,
    token_ id = None, 
    revoke_uri= None)

http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
```

Even if the access token has expired, the credential is still authorize because of the refresh token.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [2018 Youtube Python Quickstart demo app](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/python) using google-auth, you can't use oauth2client's storage.

[So here is the correct way of storing the credentials](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib/blob/master/google_auth_oauthlib/tool/__main__.py#L80)

Here is a partially working solution for google-auth, missing the correct handling of the case where the token expires:

```
import os
import json
import os.path
import google.oauth2.credentials
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow

CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secret.json"
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']
API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
API_VERSION = 'v3'

def get_authenticated_service():

  if os.path.isfile("credentials.json"):
    with open("credentials.json", 'r') as f:
      creds_data = json.load(f)
    creds = Credentials(creds_data['token'])

  else:
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, SCOPES)
    creds = flow.run_console()
    creds_data = {
          'token': creds.token,
          'refresh_token': creds.refresh_token,
          'token_uri': creds.token_uri,
          'client_id': creds.client_id,
          'client_secret': creds.client_secret,
          'scopes': creds.scopes
      }
    print(creds_data)
    with open("credentials.json", 'w') as outfile:
      json.dump(creds_data, outfile)
  return build(API_SERVICE_NAME, API_VERSION, credentials = creds)

def channels_list(service, **kwargs):
  results = service.channels().list(**kwargs).execute()
  print('This channel\'s ID is %s. Its title is %s, and it has %s views.' %
       (results['items'][0]['id'],
        results['items'][0]['snippet']['title'],
        results['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']))
   
if __name__ == '__main__':
  os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'
  service = get_authenticated_service()

  channels_list(service, part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics', forUsername='GoogleDevelopers')
  # or if the above doesn't work
  channels_list(service, part='snippet,contentDetails,statistics', id='YOUR_YOUTUBE_CHANNEL_ID')
```

Comment: Thanks this works! I just need it for a simple cli app

Comment: Have amended the code because this example may not work on API v3 since channels do not necessarily have a username attached any more. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35173130?pli=1#comment5

Answer (score 1):

If you have a refresh token then you can generate credentials for use by using  OAuth2Credentials as below

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client, GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI

client_id = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"
client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
refresh_token = "YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN"

creds = client.OAuth2Credentials(
            access_token = None, 
            client_id = client_id, 
            client_secret = client_secret, 
            refresh_token = refresh_token, 
            token_expiry = None, 
            token_uri = GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI,
            user_agent="pythonclient")
        
creds.refresh(httplib2.Http())
```

I don't know what goes in the user agent but I put a random word in there

Now you can use it to build service object and use google APIs like

```
service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)
```

In case someone wants to generate and use a offline refresh token for use without having to handle the autorization since it's for your testing then use google oauth playground to generate one. Checkout this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfWe1gPCnzc) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the entire credentials rather than only the refresh token:

```
json = credentials.to_json()
credentials = Credentials.new_from_json(json)
```

Look at the [Storage object](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#storage) which does it this way.

Comment: how will that help me to gain an access token later on?  the access token contained in the credentials expires, while the refresh token doesn't; so I have to get a new access token later.

Comment: I believe credentials.authorize(http) will handle refreshing the token automatically on a 401 response.

Comment: I got a `403` response, `insufficientPermissions Indicates that the user does not have sufficient permissions for the entity specified in the query`, which I think it needs an access token to be generated. Any idea? I am working on it currently

Comment: I use this, and it seems to be working fine for a refresh token.

Comment: I can approve that library automatically refreshes access token when it get 401 (debugged) so answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

Wow.. 2 years old question and not a good answer.. No surprise given that Google documentation is crap regarding this.

The correct way to do this is by extending the Storage class `oauth2client.client.Storage`

An example implementation(using *mongodb* collection `_google_credentials`) would be something like:

```
class Storage(oauth2client.client.Storage):

def __init__(self, key):
    super(Storage, self).__init__()
    self._key = key

def locked_get(self):
    if not self._key: return None
    data = _google_credentials.find_one({'_id': self._key})
    if not data: return None
    credentials = oauth2client.client.Credentials.new_from_json(json.dumps(data))
    credentials.set_store(self)
    return credentials

def locked_put(self, credentials):
    data = json.loads(credentials.to_json())
    _google_credentials.update_one({'_id': self._key}, {'$set': data}, 
        upsert=True)
    credentials.set_store(self)

def locked_delete(self):
    bucket.delete(self._key)
```

Then when you initially get the credentials after `step2_exchange`, you need to store them using `Storage().put`:

e.g:

```
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
Storage(user_id).put(credentials)
```

When you need the credentials again, just do:

```
credentials = Storage(user_id).get()
```

Comment: The oauth2client is deprecated, https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/oauth2client-deprecation.html
Google recommends you use google-auth https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a `Credentials` object then you can refresh it like so:

```py
if refresh:
    import google_auth_httplib2
    # credentials instanceof google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials
    credentials.refresh(google_auth_httplib2.Request(httplib2.Http()))
```

I had created the `Credentials` object from an old token JSON file like so:

```py
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
        token=token_json['access_token'],
        refresh_token=token_json['refresh_token'],
        id_token=token_json['id_token'],
        token_uri=token_json['token_uri'],
        client_id=token_json['client_id'],
        client_secret=token_json['client_secret'],
        scopes=token_json['scopes'])
```

In this way I was able to adapt some old `oauth2client` code.