# How to get a refresh token to give me a new access token using javascript or python

Tags: javascript, python, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am trying to get a new access token for clients when ever their current token expires. I have seen some examples that use ruby and some that use javascript but nonei can seem to get any of them to work. I have to be able to do this in either javascript or python as it will live on in a lambda and lambdas can use very few languages. I cant seem to get any of the examples im finding to work for some reason and figure it has to be something just a little off.

```
var GoogleTokenProvider = require('refresh-token').GoogleTokenProvider;

var tokenProvider = new GoogleTokenProvider({
refresh_token: '1/***************************Xk', 
client_id:     '930******858-t8683rc*********v2i7efg5o7.apps.googleusercontent.com', 
client_secret: 'EM-u_cQJU*******bK16EUa'
});



// Retrieve tokens via token exchange explained above or set them:
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
access_token: 'ya29.Gl**********msfwAwXBWU-EyGWu******************Z2HK9XmBIah20sCT6*************Htm9hPEDBIaml8VW',
refresh_token: '1/************************xMXk',
// Optional, provide an expiry_date (milliseconds since the Unix Epoch)
//   expiry_date: (new Date()).getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7)
});


 oauth2Client.refreshAccessToken(function(err, tokens) {
// your access_token is now refreshed and stored in oauth2Client
// store these new tokens in a safe place (e.g. database)
console.log(oauth2Client);
console.log("new",tokens);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated as this is the only thing holding  me up to get this project moving forward once again and I gotta figure this out im on a time constraint. I have a few other examples in Javascript I can provide if any body wants to see them. I am really new to pyton so I haven't delved to far in to that but thats what my main function for this part is gonna be in.

Comment: All you are doing in refreshAccessToken is logging it so that's probably not going to do much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google API: getting Credentials from refresh token with oauth2client.client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771324/google-api-getting-credentials-from-refresh-token-with-oauth2client-client)

Comment: @DaImTo Ive tried those ones, there is not even an accepted answer on that page or is there one with a decent amount of votes. and if i can see it by logging it to the screen then i can send it to my database easy enough