# connect openerp 6.1 to google spreadsheet api

Tags: python-2.7, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, openerp-6

I am unable to authenticate oauth2.0  using openerp xml-rpc, right now i am using the cmd quickstart google spreadsheet api code to read and write from openerp once i have acquired the token using another script,

## script for generating a valid token

```
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = '/opt/openerp/client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Google Sheets API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        # print (flags)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials
print get_credentials()
```

& the code, I run from within openerp 6.1, where, I accept the url for the spreadsheet as an input from which, I strip the spreadsheet id and the location or block which needs to be edited eg A2, and a value that accepts the value to be written in that location.

## Openerp 6.1 code:

```
    def get_credentials(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

        If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
        the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

        Returns:
            Credentials, the obtained credential.
        """
        home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
        credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
        if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
            os.makedirs(credential_dir)
        credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                       'sheets.googleapis.com-python-quickstart.json')
        store =Storage(credential_path)

        credentials = store.get()

        if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
            subprocess.call(['python /opt/openerp/test.py'])
            self.get_credentials(cr,uid,ids,context=context)
            # flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            # flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME

            # if flags:
            #   credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
            # else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            #   credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
            # # print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
        return credentials

    def update_sheet(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.

        Creates a Sheets API service object and prints the names and majors of
        students in a sample spreadsheet:
        https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
        """
        sheet_brw=self.browse(cr,uid,ids[0])
        get_url=sheet_brw.get_url
        rangeName=sheet_brw.update_location
        start=get_url.find('spreadsheets/d/') +15
        end=get_url.find('/edit',start)
        spreadsheetId=get_url[start:end]
        sheet_val=sheet_brw.value

        credentials = self.get_credentials(cr,uid,ids,context)
        http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        discoveryUrl = ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
                        'version=v4')
        service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http,
                                  discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)

        # spreadsheetId = '1sFhMx8VTkC_cgFfUDxdCByXkbUl7LpWSQbb_S2aIEtE'
        # rangeName = 'A2:B'
        result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
        values = result.get('values', [])
        print values
        if not values:
            print('No data found.')
        else:
            print('Medical College, Distance:')
            for row in values:
                # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                row0=row[0] if len(row) else ''
                row1=row[1] if len(row) > 1 else ''
                print('%s, %s' % (row0, row1))
        values = [
            [ str(sheet_val)
            ],
            # Additional rows ...
        ]
        body = {
            # 'valueInputOption': 'RAW',
            'values': values
        }
        result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName,valueInputOption='RAW',body=body).execute()

get_spreadsheet()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a refresh key and using the same to authorize since the refresh key never expires but can be revoked it works best for this scenario

I generated the refresh token from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19766913/4417511) and used it to generate credentials like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230541/4417511)

Finally my code for openerp is as :

```
from oauth2client import client, GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI, GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI

CLIENT_ID = "<client identifier>"
CLIENT_SECRET = "<client secret>"
REFRESH_TOKEN = "<refresh_token>"
   def get_credentials(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        credentials = client.OAuth2Credentials(
        None, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REFRESH_TOKEN, None, GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI,
        None, revoke_uri=GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI)
        credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
        return credentials

    def update_sheet(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.

        Creates a Sheets API service object and prints the names and majors of
        students in a sample spreadsheet:
        https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
        """
        sheet_brw=self.browse(cr,uid,ids[0])
        get_url=sheet_brw.get_url
        rangeName=sheet_brw.update_location
        start=get_url.find('spreadsheets/d/') +15
        end=get_url.find('/edit',start)
        spreadsheetId=get_url[start:end]
        sheet_val=sheet_brw.value

        credentials = self.get_credentials(cr,uid,ids,context)
        http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
        discoveryUrl = ('https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?'
                        'version=v4')
        service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', http=http,
                                  discoveryServiceUrl=discoveryUrl)


        # rangeName = 'A2:B'
        result = service.spreadsheets().values().get(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName).execute()
        values = result.get('values', [])
        print values
        if not values:
            print('No data found.')
        else:
            print('Medical College, Distance:')
            for row in values:
                # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
                row0=row[0] if len(row) else ''
                row1=row[1] if len(row) > 1 else ''
                print('%s, %s' % (row0, row1))
        values = [
            [ str(sheet_val)
            ],
            # Additional rows ...
        ]
        body = {
            # 'valueInputOption': 'RAW',
            'values': values
        }
        result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
            spreadsheetId=spreadsheetId, range=rangeName,valueInputOption='RAW',body=body).execute()

get_spreadsheet()
```